# dict object failing in VBA code

Tags: vba

I have following code in vba to populate a dictionary object.

```
Do
    If Not dict.Exists(rst![key]) Then
       dict.Add rst![key], rst![val]
    End If
    rst.MoveNext
Loop Until rst.EOF
```

For some reason my dictionary fails, does not add another item to the dictionary, after the first iteration. Please let me know if anybody has any thought on this.

Comment: `my dictionary fails` - how it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using a dictionary object, you have to use the Value property of your recordset in your Dictionary.Add method, otherwise it will not work. Try following

```
Do
    If Not dict.Exists(rst![key].Value) Then
       dict.Add rst![key].Value, rst![val].Value
    End If
    rst.MoveNext
Loop Until rst.EOF
```